# patch function in ARM binary to always return 0

Tags: disassembly, arm, patching

I have an ARM binary in which I want to patch a function to always return 0.
My understanding is this means I need to set `r0` register to 0.

The disassembly looks like this

```
STMFD           SP!, {R4-R6,LR}
<lots of code>
LDMFD           SP!, {R4-R6,PC}
```

Can I overwrite all of this with a `mov r0, 0` -> `0000A0E3` followed by a return (`mov pc, lr` -> `0EF0A0E1`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, returning in ARM/Thumb is to set the R0 register and return.

You can patch the program a number of ways to do what you want. You can replace the top most instructions with `mov r0, 0` and `mov pc, lr` and leaving the remaining code as is would make it not execute those instructions after `mov pc, lr` and just return to the calling function.

```
MOV R0, 0
MOV PC, LR
// leave the rest as is, it wont execute
```

You can also patch starting after  STMFD SP!, {R4-R6,LR} with MOV R0, 0 and then nopping all the way to the return statement LDMFD SP!, {R4-R6,PC}.

```
STMFD SP!, {R4-R6,LR}
MOV R0, 0
// NOP ALL THE WAY TO:
LDMFD SP!, {R4-R6,PC}
```

You can also just patch starting after `STMFD SP!, {R4-R6,LR}` with `MOV R0, 0` and then replacing the following instruction with `LDMFD SP!, {R4-R6,PC}` to return early making the rest of the code below it un-executed.

```
STMFD SP!, {R4-R6,LR}
MOV R0, 0
LDMFD SP!, {R4-R6,PC}
// leave the rest as is, it wont execute
```

Comment: Yes that is what I expected but was unsure if the `STMFD / LDMFD` was required to balance the stack